# subscribing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am completely new to Angular and I've created a project using SpringBoot 2.0.5.RELEASE, Angular 5 and spring data to build an end to end single page java web application. I use spring boot 1.5 to expose REST APIs and angular5 with routing to build the client that will consume the APIs exposed by the server.

I've defined this component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './add-user.component.html'
})
export class AddUserComponent {

  user: User = new User();

  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {

  }

  createUser(): void {
    alert ('lala');
    this.userService.createUser(this.user)
        .subscribe( data => {
          alert('User created successfully.');
        });
  }
}
```

in the page I can see the alert `lala`, but not `'User created successfully.'` but I have no idea why

The link address when I create a user is this is this one `http://localhost:4200/api/users`

This is my `proxy.config.json` file:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080/user-portal",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

and from curl is fine :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:8080/user-portal/api/users"
```

and user.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { User } from '../models/user.model';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    private userUrl = '/api/users';

  public getUsers() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.userUrl);
  }

  public deleteUser(user) {
    return this.http.delete(this.userUrl + '/'+ user.id);
  }

  public createUser(user) {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.userUrl, user);
  }

}
```

Comment: You'll have to recheck 'createUser' in UserService and make sure everything is working fine there. Try putting in an alert to your service.

Comment: any errors in the console

Comment: 1'st debug spring boot app. add a debug pointer to the controller and see.

Comment: can you show user service?

Comment: can you try this -> return this.http.post<User>(this.userUrl,JSON.stringify( user),this.httpOptions );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, best not to use alert. Use console.log. Secondly, you are only handling success, you are not handling failure. Do this:

```
createUser(): void {
  console.log('lala');
  this.userService.createUser(this.user)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log('User created successfully', data);
    },
    err => {
      console.log('There was an error', err);
    },
    () => {
      console.log('I have completed now and nothing will ever be emitted from this Observable again');
    });
}
```

The error handler will be executed if the HTTP response is not a success response, viz if the status code of the response is not in the 2xx range.

Check your browser network tab also to see if the HTTP request is failing.

You prob also want to debug this:

```
public createUser(user) {
  console.log('userUrl', this.userUrl)
  console.log('user', user)
  return this.http.post<User>(this.userUrl, user);
}
```

To make sure all is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome hit F12 to open the dev tools and go to the network tab. Make sure that a request is being made to the end point and that it is not throwing and error.